# how to updating a textview with a loop on click

Tags: android

On the first click, the text view change to some text, and in the second click the text will change to an other text.
I started to write it with a switch statement:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

     switch () {
          case ();
          text.setText("You have clicked once");

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

create a counter before on start and initialize it to 0

```
int clickCount = 0;
```

then in your onClick() method increment the counter and set the text as you need

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     clickCount++;
     switch(clickCount){
          case 1:text.setText("Your Text Here"); break;
          case 2:text.setText("Your Text Here"); break;
             .....
             .....
             .....
          default:text.setText("Your Text Here"); break;
     }  
  }
```

Comment: I guess he wanna add particular text on each click

Comment: Good you edited the answer, It will be helpful to set particular text based on click count

Comment: Thanks, but i want that the  all  text will change to another.

Comment: You can put whatever text you want

Answer (score 1):

> For your question answer is like this, on each click we are increasing the count, so that you can set required text to the textview.

```
int count=0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
     switch(count)
      {
       case 0:
       text.setText("You have clicked once");
       break;

       case 1:
       text.setText("You have clicked twice");
       break;
       .....

       default:
       break;
      }
   count++;
    }
```